# System-wide Google Search shortcut for Chrome (macOS version)

Tags: macos, mac, applescript, google-chrome, shortcut

on the macOS, does anyone know how to set up a system-wide global keyboard shortcut to Google Search the selected text within the Chrome browser? (this could be easily done for Safari but not sure how for a third party browser)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  How do you do this for safari and what step or error blocks you with the chrome browser?

Comment: What’s a system wide google search for chrome.  System wide inherently means outside of Chrome.   Can you explain what you’re trying to accomplish?

Comment: @bmike @Allan, If you go to `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services -> Search with Google`, and choose a keyboard combination for that: Wherever you select a text with the cursor on the system and then you press that keyboard combination, Safari will get opened with a Google Search of that selected text. I'm aiming to do the same with Chrome. For Safari, the system-wide Google Search shortcut is system integrated, but not for a third party browser. Maybe this would be possible with Applescript.

Comment: @KhashayarAbri set your default browser to chrome

Comment: @ankii I already did. This doesn't help.

Comment: You would have to set up your own system service with Automator that uses Chrome instead of Safari. It can be done, would just take some AppleScript and Automator knowledge. The first thing you should google is how to make a system service with Automator. The once you have that down, look at the AppleScript part.